# creating tensor by composition of smaller tensors

Tags: pytorch

I would like to create a 4x4 tensor that is composed of four smaller 2x2 tensors in this manner:

The tensor I would like to create:

```py
in_t = torch.tensor([[14,  7,  6,  2],
                     [ 4,  8, 11,  1],
                     [ 3,  5,  9, 10],
                     [12, 15, 16, 13]])
```

I would like to create this tensor composed from these four smaller tensors:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[14, 7], [ 4,  8]])
b = torch.tensor([[6,  2], [11,  1]])
c = torch.tensor([[3,  5], [12, 15]])
d = torch.tensor([[9, 10], [16, 13]])
```

I have tried to use `torch.cat` like this:

```py
mm_ab = torch.cat((a,b,c,d), dim=0)
```

but I end up with an 8x2 tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the layout of your tensor and achieve the desired result with a combination of [`torch.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) and [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html?highlight=permute). You can perform an *outer* transpose followed by an *inner* transpose:

```
>>> stack = torch.stack((a,b,c,d))
tensor([[[14,  7],
         [ 4,  8]],

        [[ 6,  2],
         [11,  1]],

        [[ 3,  5],
         [12, 15]],

        [[ 9, 10],
         [16, 13]]])
```

Reshape-tranpose-reshape-transpose-reshape:

```
>>> stack.reshape(4,2,-1).transpose(0,1).reshape(-1,2,4).transpose(0,1).reshape(-1,4)
tensor([[14,  7,  6,  2],
        [ 4,  8, 11,  1],
        [ 3,  5,  9, 10],
        [12, 15, 16, 13]])
```

Essentially, reshapes allow you to group and view your tensor differently while transpose operation will alter its layout (it won't remain contiguous) meaning you can achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you concatenate all your tensors this way below, you will get exactly your output:

| tensor a | tensor b |
| --- | --- |
| **tensor c** | **tensor d** |

You really started with a good and easy approach, this is the completion of your attempt:

```
p1 = torch.concat((a,b),axis=1)
p2 = torch.concat((c,d),axis=1)
p3 = torch.concat((p1,p2),axis=0)
print(p3)

#output
tensor([[14,  7,  6,  2],
        [ 4,  8, 11,  1],
        [ 3,  5,  9, 10],
        [12, 15, 16, 13]])
```